# Where can I find publicly accessible paternoster elevators?

Tags: where-on-earth

[Paternosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternoster_lift) look fun, but (as far as I know, at least in Western Europe) they have almost all been replaced by regular elevators for safety reasons.

**Are there any publicly-accessible paternosters left I can ride in?**

Wikipedia mentions a few, but they seem to be in private buildings.

If you can give a site where I can find them that would be appreciated.

[image]
(Animation from Wikipedia by RokerHRO; CC license)

Comment: The phrase to search for is *active paternoster elevator*

Comment: @Mathilde Lots of them in Prague, there is a map on the internet of all of them.

Comment: All these answers given in comments...

Comment: @CGCampbell The question should be closed ASAP as being too broad, so it's not correct to answer it. Commenting however seems "okayish".

Comment: Here is a cool one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro3Fc_yG3p0

Comment: An attended parking garage (I believe it was the Halle's department store garage, across Huron Rd. from the store in downtown Cleveland. The garage is still there...) that we went to when I was a boy had something like this for the attendants to go from the ground level up to the parking levels. However, there was no "box" to ride in - instead, there were little platforms and an appropriately placed grab-bar attached to a broad belt, and about a 1 meter by 1 meter hole in each floor that the "elevator" went through. Insanely dangerous. I **SO** wanted to ride on it when I was a kid!!! :-)

Comment: There is (or was) a cool one in Berlin - any local will direct you!  Great question!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is a fantastic website (albeit in German) called [PatList](http://www.flemming-hamburg.de/patlist.htm) ([Archived Version](https://web.archive.org/web/20190825203711/http://www.flemming-hamburg.de:80/patlist.htm)) that lists every paternoster elevator in existence, as well as whether or not its publicly accessible. Currently there's about **300** such elevators left in operation (of which at least 50 are freely accessible to the public), so they're *far* from rare. Google Translate works well with the site, so it should be easy to find places to visit.

Overall your best bet would be to travel to Germany and Czech Republic, as they have the bulk of the worlds remaining paternosters in operation. In fact I rode one this morning here in Prague :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87420/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathanreez-where-can-i-find-publicly-accessible-patern).

Comment: The PatList appears incomplete and/or biased to places in Germany; the only paternoster I've been (which is public) is not listed (and not in Germany).

Answer (score 23):

The paternoster at the Arts Tower in the University of Sheffield, UK ([Universities web-page](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/news/nr/sheffield-arts-tower-paternoster-1.753518),  [BBC video](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-england-south-yorkshire-42997131/sheffield-university-s-paternoster-lift-in-motion)) certainly used to be open to the public. These [forum](https://www.sheffieldforum.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1030411) posts from 2012 and a number of more recent [Tripadviser](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186364-d213602-Reviews-The_Arts_Tower-Sheffield_South_Yorkshire_England.html) reviews suggest that this is still the case. The university also publishes a [self guided tour (pdf)](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.653332!/file/Self_Guided_Campus_Tour.pdf) which includes the tower and its blurb does talk about the paternoster but also states that there is "Limited access to inside building".

Alternatively you could book yourself onto a public event inside the building. Monday to Fridays 15th to the 29th of June an [architectural exhibition](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/architecture/about/summer-exhibition) is taking place in the arts tower. Or you can view their full [list of events](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/whatson/opendaysandexhibitions). The university has also traditionally opened one building up to members of the public to tour in September each year as part of the [heritage open days scheme](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/whatson/heritageopenday), the arts tower opened in 2012 and the university didn't take part last year (2017). Weather or not they will take part in 2018 and which building will likely be known around mid July [(Source)](https://www.heritageopendays.org.uk/visiting). Obviously there is no guarantee that the paternoster will be running on any given day/time. But i'd image its most likely to be the case from around 9-5 during term time. The building does feature other normal lifts which may be in use instead - something which I would imagine is more likely going to be done for a late evening event or on a  weekend/event out of term time. You could send an email and try and ask the exact opening times.

Finally, you could also visit on an [open day](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/undergraduate/opendays) with potential students, there are a handful of dates over the summer or the students union offer more regular [tours](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/undergraduate/opendays/campustourfaqs) to non-students. They note that "Although the campus tour will take you past most of the academic buildings, if you wish to visit a specific department and speak to a member of staff then you will need to contact them directly, at least two weeks prior to your visit to the University." you could ask if there tour includes the Arts Tower, or ask if they would be willing to while you are there. While these tours are open to the public, they will of course be designed for prospective students of the university.

Comment: [This video from 2015](https://youtu.be/YgJBD1wf-YQ) seems to think that it's still open to the public.

Comment: If you want a go on the paternoster at Sheffield University, try visiting on a university open day when the Arts Tower is more likely to be open o the public. I went in July 2015 (I was a genuine prospective student, but I wasn't going to miss the paternoster)

Answer (score 10):

Similar to [Hilmar's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/115496/63571), the city hall of Stuttgart, Germany also has a Paternoster that is publicly accessible and frequently mentioned on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187291-d7084002-r342423930-Rathaus-Stuttgart_Baden_Wurttemberg.html).

It was opened in 1956 and was temporarily shut down in 2015 due to legal issues. You can watch it being re-opened on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJzUmpdqGb0).

You can visit the Paternoster during the opening hours of city hall, usually from 8am to 6pm on weekdays.

[image: Paternoster in Stuttgart city hall]
<sup>Image by [РБМК-1500](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:RBMK-1500) from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Paternosteraufzug_rathaus.JPG), [CC BY-SA 3.0 DE](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/deed.de)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Bochum in Germany has one in city hall that's a local city favorite. It was closed in 2013 for legal reasons but re-opened in 2015 by the mayor herself.

[She hits the button at around 1:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6TqGuv6FDg&t=1m50s).

Comment: Duisburg City Hall or some similar official building also has one. It seems that old City Halls have a knack for it.

Answer (score 9):

Vienna city hall,
active and publicly available Paternoster,
open from 06:30 a.m. thru 4 p.m. local time on working days.
North entrance #6 (Felderstrasse)

https://club.wien.at/magazin/lifestyle/paternoster-im-rathaus/

They celebrate its 100th birthday this year.

Comment: That one's just around the corner from me - no travel required. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few Paternosters still operating in Prague - the most accessible one is located in New City Hall, and there are others (I am not sure if they operate) in the buildings of CTU Campus.

Answer (score 2):

The government building in **Copenhagen, Denmark** has one; although I'm not aware of how many hoops you'd have to go through to obtain access.

Somebody posted this [video from the Christiansborg elevators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F33xF-Ijhak) -- I would not have filmed it in 90* rotation!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the one in the [GrossMarkt Halle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fmarkthalle) (in Ostend, Frankfurt am Main), now the ECB is still working and accessible. When I worked in the building (had an office there) I used to ride it everyday.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit three of them in Brno. They are at these locations:

1. Post office next to main train station (there is big sign POŠTA, you can't miss it)
2. Faculty of Mechanical Engineering which is part of University of technology (address: Technická 2
   616 00 Brno)
3. Brno city hall (address: Malinovského náměstí 3 (Malinovsky square 3))

Answer (score 2):

There is also a paternoster in Szeged, Hungary, in the Country hall ([location](https://maps.app.goo.gl/B39RzhCoydJXwgk2A)). It's hard to find anything about it online (except a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBKINXdhFfU) and a [news article](https://szegedma.hu/kozelet/2014/09/a-13-as-kabin-miatt-is-kerulik-a-szegedi-paternosztert-fotok) in Hungarian), and what can be found is in Hungarian, but as a local I can assure you it's there and - to my knowledge - still operational.

[image]]

Answer (score 1):

Rathaus Schöneberg, Berlin, Germany has 2 Paternoster (in the back part of the building) that anyone who visits the building can use.

The two publicly accessible paternosters were manufactured in 1914 by the Carl Flohr company (later Flohr-Otis).

It was shown in the television series [Babylon Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_Berlin), where many of the scenes of the Interiors of the police headquarters were filmed.

When I worked there, they were faster to use than the 2 lifts situated in the front part of the building.

An attempt to close them down in 2015 was made, but after only 3 weeks the ordinance was revolked.

> Das Bundesarbeitsministerium hat mit ihrer „Betriebssicherheitsverordnung“ im Jahr 2015 ein erneutes Paternosterverbot auf den Weg gebracht, das am 01. Juni 2015 in Kraft trat und das Fahren mit Personenumlaufaufzügen nur noch betriebsangehörigen eingewiesenen Personen erlaubte.
>
> > In 2015, the Federal Ministry of Labor launched a renewed ban on paternoster lifts with its "Industrial Safety Ordinance", which came into force on June 1, 2015 and only allowed people to use the passenger lifts that had been instructed by the company.
>
> Die Verordnung stieß auf heftige Gegenwehr und wurde schon gute drei Wochen später vom Bundeskabinett und dem Bundesrat wieder gekippt beziehungsweise geändert. Wenn die Betreiber sich verpflichten, “durch zusätzliche Maßnahmen Gefährdungen bei der Benutzung zu vermeiden”, dann könnten die Paternoster wieder genutzt werden.
>
> > The ordinance met with fierce resistance and was overturned or amended just over three weeks later by the Federal Cabinet and the Federal Council.  If the operators undertake to “avoid hazards during use by taking additional measures”, then the paternoster could be used again.

[image]

---

**Sources**:

- [Paternoster im Rathaus Schöneberg](https://www.berlin.de/ba-tempelhof-schoeneberg/ueber-den-bezirk/historisches/artikel.591646.php) (in German)

  - 2023-09-06: Important note: the paternosters are currently temporarily closed due to construction work.
  - [Babylon Berlin - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_Berlin)

Answer (score 1):

I used to study in Frankfurt University. One of the building, the Campus Westend (also called I.G. Faber Haus) has lots of it! I rode on it many times. Afaik you don't have to be a student to access the building.